# Propel toJson or exportTo('JSON') not working with Laravel

Tags: php, json, orm, laravel, propel

I have configured Propel to work with Laravel with the help of http://picqer.com/blog/propel-with-laravel. All model queries are working fine and all data is being fetched properly.

However, the `toJSON` and `exportTo('JSON')` methods are not working neither on the Objects or nor on the PropelObjectCollection returned by certain queries.

The exceptions thrown by Laravel are:

For `exportTo('JSON')` and `toJSON()` all caps method

```
Unknown parser class "PropelArrayParser"
```

For `toJson()` method:

```
Unknown parser class "PropelJsonParser"
```

I think the problem lies somewhere with autoload of Laravel. I am perhaps missing an entry that'd help it locate PropelJsonParser file.

P.S. I have no idea what effects 'php artisan dump-autoload' causes. But I did run it as per tutorial.

The build.properties file looks like:

```
propel.project = QuranApp
propel.database = mysql
propel.mysql.tableType = InnoDB
propel.database.url = mysql:host=localhost;dbname=quransociety
propel.database.user = user
propel.database.password = password
propel.disableIdentifierQuoting = false
propel.php.dir = ${propel.project.dir}/../../models
propel.output.dir = ${propel.project.dir}/../../database/propel
propel.phpconf.dir = ${propel.project.dir}/conf
propel.schema.dir = ${propel.project.dir}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added those two lines in laravel start.php (at the beginning):

```
set_include_path(dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/parser' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/parser/PropelJSONParser.php';
```

so basically I'm including them by hand, and this error is gone. There should be other way, that plays nice along with larvel autoload mechanism, but so far I didn't solve it differently